# RSpec load time incredible long on OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

We use Mongodb and RSpec for our project. On my OS X machine RSpec for a single controller runs in:

`Finished in 0.24996 seconds (files took 25.39 seconds to load)`

on the other hand my friend has Ubuntu and for him the same spec runs in:

`Finished in 0.27996 seconds (files took 4.05 seconds to load)`

Loading time is more than 6 times longer on my machine. What could be the reason?

P.S. Not using OS X is not a solution :/

#### Update:

More information about our setup:

We both use ruby 2.2. We run specs via guardfile with `cmd: bundle exec rspec`

My friend uses rbenv and `which rspec` returns

"/home/dan/.rbenv/shims/rspec`

I use rvm and `which rspec` returns:

```
$ which rspec
rspec: aliased to bundled_rspec
$ which bundled_rspec
bundled_rspec () {
    _run-with-bundler rspec $@
```

#### Update 2:

I just cloned https://github.com/eliotsykes/rspec-rails-examples and ran rspec. It took over 36s to load files. So it is not mongodb related. I just noticed that rails server is also loading very long.

```
> time rspec -v
3.3.2

real    0m2.539s
user    0m1.067s
sys 0m0.185s
```

Comment: Are you running the same command? Is your Ruby and project setup identical?

Comment: @Stefan, What do you mean by project setup? We both use Ruby 2.2

Comment: There are many ways to install Ruby and to invoke RSpec. Any version managers like rvm, rbenv, chruby, anything like vagrant? Are the files located on your hard disk or on a remote system? Are you running RSpec via `rspec` or `bundle exec rspec` or `rake`? Are you invoking the same executable (what does `which rspec` return)?

Comment: @Stefan look updated question

Comment: What does `time rspec -v` output, i.e. how long is just to load environment for rspec? What RVM version do you use `rvm -v`?

Comment: @AlexeyShein `time rspec spec/.../.rb -v`: 3.3.2       4.26 real         1.23 user         0.33 sys  `rvm -v`: rvm 1.26.11 (latest)

Comment: BTW, starting with RVM 1.11 you don't need any `bundle exec` calls. Run `gem regenerate_binstubs` once and forget `bundle exec` as a nightmare. See details here: https://rvm.io/integration/bundler#rubygems-bundler

Comment: Please, run `time rspec -v` exactly, without any tests, so we can measure just rspec loading time alone without any test running time. For example, my time for that command is `rspec -v  0.72s user 0.09s system 98% cpu 0.826 total`, i.e. total time is `0.826` seconds.

Comment: @AlexeyShein `time rspec -v`  -> `3.3.2 5.81 real         1.43 user         0.40 sys`

Answer (score 18):

### Bundler

Looks like some bundler loading issue for me. I'd recommend to make some more measurements. Do you use 1 gemset per project or store everything in 1 gemset (it's true if you don't use any)? If you have lots of gems in 1 directory (i.e. 1 gemset for all) it will eventually slows down bundler a lot, since it needs to traverse more paths to make its job.

```
bundle | wc -l # how many gems bundler uses in your current project
gem list -q | wc -l # how many gems in your gemset
```

If `gem list -q | wc -l` reports quite large value (I have `237` and everything seems normal for me), maybe you need to split installed gems into a separate gemset per project.

Make some more measurements with `time` command, look for the `real` value, it's total sum.

First, remove your `bundled_rspec` wrapper, it's not needed with [latest RVM](https://rvm.io/integration/bundler#rubygems-bundler) versions.

Then measure your rspec loading with and without Bundler:

```
time rspec -v # with implicit bundler loading, rubygems-bundler gem is in use
time NOEXEC_DISABLE=1 rspec -v # without bundler, disable rubygems-bundler gem for this call`
```

If `time rspec -v` gives you big numbers even for project with relatively small Gemfile, it's a bundler issue.

### Rails

Next bottleneck is usually Rails itself. Try measuring one test that doesn't load Rails (i.e. just `spec_helper`) and then test with rails (i.e. with `rails_helper`).

As soon you start seeing big difference in numbers, you'll know where you have a problem.

### Spring

As a quick-fix solution to improve rails performance is a usage of [`spring` gem](https://github.com/rails/spring). If you use Rails 4.1+ Spring is already enabled.

To enable Spring for `rspec` add to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'spring-commands-rspec', group: :development
```

and run

```
$ bundle install
$ spring binstub --all
```

Last command will generate wrappers for all spring supported binaries in your project's `bin` folder (take a look there and don't forget to commit them). After that you should run `rspec` with `bin/rspec`. First run will be still slow, but all consequent runs should be fast enough since Rails will be already loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately I've just discovered it isn't project related issue. Rails/RSpec has extremely long loading time on all ruby versions managed by rvm :/

Comment: bin/rspec is ~50% faster than rspec. But still it's 14 sec loading time

Comment: Check your gems and initializers folder, maybe something there slows things down.

Comment: Can't be, because only my machine is effected wth such loading time. My teammates have 2 sec loading time.

Comment: Try `gem pristine --all`, this will put your gems into fresh state.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no improvement

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Try reinstalling ruby (or getting a fresh version) and start from scratch.

Comment: I'll reinstall OS X today, let's see what will happen

Comment: @FilipBartuzi what effect you got after reinstalling the OS? You have solved the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyShein there was an improvement but still there was noticeable delay. I ended up switching my dev machine so I haven't really solved it.

Comment: Anything for ruby <= 2.3.0 for loading rspec files faster?

Comment: Adding gem 'spring-commands-rspec' works for me! From 18 secs to 1.31 sec to load

Comment: I found my bottleneck seems to be in the spring
After I run `spring binstub --all` and run the spec with`bin/rspec`. The loading time decrease from 20s to 2s, which is a significant improvement for me. 
Thanks!